# No WiFi On Logon Screen

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, login, windows-domain

When logging onto the domain via WiFi, logon scripts do not always run.  I believe this is because the Wi-Fi card is not yet connected.

How can I connect to a Wi-Fi access point before the logon (ie: on the logon screen)?

Comment: Do you know if your Wi-Fi network requires just a password, such as WPA2-PSK (a.k.a. WPA2-Personal) uses? Or does it require a certificate, or a username/password pair, such as WPA2-Enterprise (WPA2 with 802.1X) uses? Well either way, it comes down to storing your wireless network login credentials in your "local system" store, not in your user account. I haven't done it on Windows in a long time, but hopefully someone else will come along and give you a full Answer on how to do it.

Comment: @Spiff - you are right that we need more info. I've seen it done with 3rd party software, don't think I've seen it with native configuration. It would represent some significant security risks possibly.

Comment: @JulianKnight It's quite commonly done in institutional environments such as enterprises and schools, so that the institution's laptops stay on the network even when no one is logged in, for the sake of remote management, backups, etc. I'm sure I've done it on a clean install of Windows (I think it was with MMC), but it's been a long time.

Comment: Indeed, that's where I've seen it done with 3rd party software - commonly vpn software.